# logic_less mode in slim, with rails 4.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, template-engine, slim-lang

I am new to [slim templating engine](http://slim-lang.com/), I want to use the logic less mode, but I cannot come to how to do that with Rails 4.2, I tried the instructions described in the [slim doc page](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/slim/file/doc/logic_less.md). but in vain.
so how can I use it?

Comment: I get empty body when adding `gem 'slim', require: 'slim/logic_less'` to my Gemfile. Documentation is not helpful.

Comment: @Sinbadsoft.com That's what I get as well.